# Firebird select non existing columns

Tags: orm, firebird

Is it anyhow possible to return NULL values for non-existing columns in Firebird?
Let's say you have an ORM Framework and want to support multiple database versions, wherein some tables columns exist or not.
So in case, a column does not exist, is it possible to return a NULL value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in Firebird itself that would allow you to do that. Selecting from a non-existing column is an error, and with good reason.

To allow for something like this, you would need to have your ORM support this and have it rewrite the queries based on the underlying table structure, which is not an easy thing to do, and on top of that a very unusual requirement. Alternatively, you should consider writing an API with implementations for the different database versions, and select the right implementation based on the underlying database.

But the only real and viable solution, would be to either have your application refuse to work with a wrong database version (eg if the db version is too high), or otherwise make it automatically upgrade the structure (eg if the db version is too low).

Comment: he can also use updatable views in ALL his databases, including Firebird one, that would provide the compatibility level and would provide stub values for columns, not appearing in the actual tables

Comment: @Arioch'The Good point, but it feels like over-engineering a workaround instead of dealing with the actual problem (an earlier version of this comment assumed it was to a different answer...)